# Regex help to include the start of a string but exclude 2 values at the end while making the result look readable

Tags: regex

I have some values like so:

```
meep.moop.foo.bar.abc
meep.moop.foo.bar.abc_xyz
meep.moot.foo.bar.def_ghi
meep.mool.foo.bar.jkl
meep.moop.foo.bar.mno
meep.moor.foo.bar.pqr
```

I have 1 regex that makes it look nice and neat and gives the values

```
/meep.([^.]+)/

abc
abc_xyz
def_ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

But now I need to exclude the values that end in xyz and ghi
I got this to return just those 2 results

```
^(.*?(xyz|ghi)[^$]*)$
```

But now I need to combine the 2 so that the list looks nice, but I don't see the old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example capture all after the last dot till the end of the string, and then assert not abc or xyz to the left using a lookbehind if that is supported

```
^meep.*\.([^.\n]+)$(?<!abc|xyz)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNU9vf/1)

Or you can use a lookahead approach matching until the last dot, and from that point on assert that the string does not end with abc or xyz.

```
^meep.*\.(?![^.\n]*(?:abc|xyz)$)([^.\n]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SozhsB/1)

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally

Comment: And if I wanted to filter out moor from the value `meep.moor.foo.bar.pqr` ?

Comment: You can use `^meep\.(?!moor\.).*$`

Comment: One more - I'm pretty close to getting this working, but got the order of my data wrong. If the values are `meep.abc_xyz.foo.bar
meep.abc.foo.bar
meep.abcd_lmn.foo.bar` and I need to filter out the ones with xyz and drop the foo.bar off the end?

Comment: @DarWright You can for example use a capture group to capture the part before `.foo.bar` like `^(meep\.(?![\w.]*xyz)[\w.]*)\.foo\.bar$` https://regex101.com/r/Q9llnG/1